# Growing Decision trees with Rpart and Tree packages

Tags: r, classification

I need to understand how the splitting criteria works in these two packages, while growing a tree, and I was unable to do so by reading the respective documentation. Can anyone explain to me the process, or point out where I can find a good explanation online?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to google their vignettes? For example, the vignettes for rpart details how the package uses the Gini index to build a tree, cross-validation to prune it.

In general, vignette is the first thing you should check for any R package.

Comment: I have read the rpart vignette, and I was finding a bit difficult to understand it, therefore I tried to find it somewhere, without any luck. But I found no information regarding the splitting criteria within the tree package vignette.